# network.host setting for Docker running ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a docker in my ubuntu host with the following:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch6.6.1 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
```

Later on when I query like so, I get failure:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

The failure looks like so:

curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'

```
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/dcac22e9-6b6f-443b-8497-c093dd6bb804.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

So, my question is:

1. How do I start elasticsearch on docker and publish the ports 9200
   and 9300 to the host?
2. Is network.host=_ *site* _ setting required?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you show result of `docker logs elasticsearch6.6.1` or are you sure that it properly set up?

Comment: Generating script.
Script contents:
docker logs elasticsearch6.6.1
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7944d5fd-4b1c-4e4c-946f-c2d1995fe88a.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
##[section]Finishing: Get Elasticsearch logs

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the image that you have mentioned, please check the logs of the container as you might have an error similar to this:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

In my case solved by: `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` then when i try the `curl` command it works as expected:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "WgMEnP1",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "2USHCgsWTQOWK5g76uOnNQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "1fd8f69",
    "build_date" : "2019-02-13T17:10:04.160291Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```